# How to dynamically index the tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch, tensor

For example, I got a tensor:

```
tensor = torch.rand(12, 512, 768)
```

And I got an index list, say it is:

```
[0,2,3,400,5,32,7,8,321,107,100,511]
```

I wish to select 1 element out of 512 elements on dimension 2 given the index list. And then the tensor's size would become `(12, 1, 768)`.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also a way just using PyTorch and avoiding the loop using *indexing* and  [**`torch.split`**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.split):

```
tensor = torch.rand(12, 512, 768)

# create tensor with idx
idx_list = [0,2,3,400,5,32,7,8,321,107,100,511]
# convert list to tensor
idx_tensor = torch.tensor(idx_list) 

# indexing and splitting
list_of_tensors = tensor[:, idx_tensor, :].split(1, dim=1)
```

When you call `tensor[:, idx_tensor, :]` you will get a tensor of shape:
 `(12, len_of_idx_list, 768)`. 
Where the second dimension depends on your number of indices.

Using [**`torch.split`**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.split) this tensor is split into a *list* of tensors of shape: `(12, 1, 768)`.

So finally `list_of_tensors` contains tensors of the shape:

```
[torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768]),
 torch.Size([12, 1, 768])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly slice it using the index and then use [**`torch.unsqueeze()`**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze) to *promote* the 2D tensor to 3D:

```
# inputs
In [6]: tensor = torch.rand(12, 512, 768)
In [7]: idx_list = [0,2,3,400,5,32,7,8,321,107,100,511]

# slice using the index and then put a singleton dimension along axis 1
In [8]: for idx in idx_list:
   ...:     sampled_tensor = torch.unsqueeze(tensor[:, idx, :], 1)
   ...:     print(sampled_tensor.shape)
   ...:     
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
```

---

Alternatively, if you want it even more terse code and don't want to use [**`torch.unsqueeze()`**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze), then use:

```
In [11]: for idx in idx_list:
    ...:     sampled_tensor = tensor[:, [idx], :]
    ...:     print(sampled_tensor.shape)
    ...:     
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
torch.Size([12, 1, 768])
```

---

Note: there's no need to use a `for` loop if you wish to do this slicing only for one `idx` from `idx_list`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tensor.gather()` function:

```
tensor = torch.rand(12, 512, 768)
ind = torch.tensor([0,2,3,400,5,32,7,8,321,107,100,511]).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(-1).expand(-1,-1,768) # shape (12,1,768)
tensor.gather(dim = 1, index = ind) # # shape (12,1,768)
```