# How to use list as index with pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

For example, a 2d tensor:

```
>>> t = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

And a list `l = [0, 1]`

If I execute `t[l]`, then it ends up printing the 0th and first line of `t`.

But what if I want to use `l` as an index? I expect to use `l` to find the element at 0th row and 1th column. In other words, I expect the same result as `t[0, 1]` or `t[0][1]`.

And I want to use it in more than 2d dimensions as well. Using `l` with length `n` as an index to track elements in `n` dimensions tensor.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55529236/how-to-dynamically-index-the-tensor-in-pytorch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC You can do this for given scenario - `t[tuple(l)]`

```
t
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]])
l
[0, 1]

t[tuple(l)]        # equivalent to t[(0,1)] or t[0,1]
tensor(2)
```

Comment: @P.Zhang I will try to improve answer if you can add possible input for list `l` and expected output for same.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a recursive function to solve this, maybe someone has a more elegant solution?

```
def list_as_index(t, l):
    if not l:
        return t
    else:
        return list_as_index(t[l[0]], l[1:])
```

Comment: I think Dishin's answer is better.